# Counting in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, count

Is there a way to keep efficient counting on Entity Framework? Please, any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to count rows on an EF query, but the count goes in timeout, nevertheless the query itself it is ok.

Tried with `.AsNoTracking()` also.

Example:

```
ObjGetIndexedViewResult.TotRecord = listDocuments.AsNoTracking()
                                                 .Select(x => new { x.id })
                                                 .Count();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A good thing to do first is check the Ouput console, the SQL query generated by Entity Framework is logged in there (and edit your question to show us). But ultimately, the count will call your DB, and it might be useful to know which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I will do just `listDocuments.Count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for bothering ya, just found the solution!

with .Distinct().

```
   ObjGetIndexedViewResult.TotRecord = listDocuments.Distinct().AsNoTracking().Select(x => new { x.id }).Count();
```

Comment: Pity you don't explain what ListDocuments is. Is it an IEnumerable of something? Apparently :istDocuments has some equal objectsl? Don't all documents have unique Id? And why is `NoTracking()` needed? Why not just `var result = listDocuments.Count()`?

Comment: Sorry mate, ListDocuments  Is an IEnumerable , yes. And all documents have unique Id, Yes! I tried NoTracking()to implement a fast solution, the query runs on a 400 milions rows Database, and goes in timeout. Still looking for a faster solution ...

Comment: So it is a query on a database, and still an IQueryable. The database never sends original records to your dbContext, only the result if your query. Since you are requesting a Count(), your original records won't be tracked. In this query NoTracking  has no influence in timing

Answer (score 1):

```
ObjGetIndexedViewResult.TotRecord.Equals(listDocuments.Distinct().AsNoTracking().Select(x => new { x.id }).Count());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ObjGetIndexedViewResult.TotRecord = listDocuments.AsNoTracking().Select(x => new { x.id }).Count();
```

use

```
Distinct().
```